# Unable to see text on Unity 5 running through wine on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unity-game-engine, wine

I installed unity 5 on my ubuntu desktop. But when i am running it, it is not coming like this i.e. no text is shown. [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you don't have required MS fonts(also it uses IE8).

Try to install [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks), and then running

```
winetricks tahoma corefonts ie8
```

There are is [Unity3D-Wine-Support repository on GitHub](https://github.com/Unity3D-Wine-Support/Unity3D-on-Wine)(with almost same aproach) and pretty big [Unity3d Wiki page about running editor on Linux](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Running_Unity_on_Linux_through_Wine)(with several approaches) - you can check them out.

Comment: This didn't work for me (on mint) but this was a problem for the 4.x versions of Unity and so may well be a problem for others (and indeed the problem this user is seeing).  Nice links.

Comment: For the record, with wine-staging 5.0rc1, the Unity game I was having font trouble with started working properly after installing `corefonts`, then `tahoma`, but not yet installing `ie8`. (No clue whether it needed both or just `tahoma`.)

Answer (score 1):

Unity 5 is working with Wine, even the store! And I didn't need to configure any extra files as with 4.6. At least for me...
I guess you need to install the tahoma script as stated here:

https://github.com/Unity3D-Wine-Support/Unity3D-on-Wine/issues/43#issuecomment-77771887

(Tested @ Ubuntu 14.04, Wine 1.7.37 and PlayOnLinux 4.2.2)

Comment: This didn't fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that upgrading to the latest wine solved this problem for me.
Unity 5.0.1f1 + wine 1.7.38 is working for me now.

There are still some other problems that have work arounds described on other wine+unity threads that you will have to deal with (I needed to force strict redraw order, install the right versions of mono, and possibly fonts etc, I can't recall but there are well known solutions to those problems).

Answer (score 0):

You may have to copy and paste your fonts into another folder.  I encountered this problem while running Fruity Loops on wine in Ubuntu.  Copying the font files fixed the problem.  I'm sorry, at the moment I can't recall which folder I copied to (it may have been a wine config folder, or somewhere in the Land of Program Files) but I'll try to follow up later.

Answer (score -1):

Unity is not compatible with Wine.  Neither are designer programs like MobiOne and GameMaker 6 +

Comment: MobiOne have bugs on Wine, yes. But GameMaker [works totally fine on Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2965) by default and without any tricks.

Comment: @rufanov It's image based - Mobione.  And it was made in Visual Studio or something along those lines

Comment: Unity 4.6 was compatible with wine and I'm assuming that Unity 5 is also though I to am having this font problem.  It's not unusual for new wine installs.